# Powershell Add-Member with an expression for the value

Tags: powershell, calculated-property

Trying to add a new member to an array of powershell objects, can't get the expression to evaluate. Here's some example code:

```
$testData =
@([pscustomobject]@{Name="Cat";Legs=4},
[pscustomobject]@{Name="Parrot";Legs=2},
[pscustomobject]@{Name="Snake";Legs=0})

# this works
$testData | Select-Object Name, Legs, @{N='CopyName';E={$_.Name}}

# why doesnt this work?
$testData | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "CopyName" -NotePropertyValue $_.Name
$testData
```

(Using Powershell 7)

Comment: You need a process block to properly reference `$_.Name` in that case, you can use `ForEach-Object` for example.

Comment: `Add-Member` works on a single object, not an array of objects, whereas `Select-Object` does

Comment: Thanks so I guess I need to use a loop, but if it works for Select-Object why dont they make it work for Add-Member?

Comment: @Theo, note that because `$testData` is supplied _via the pipeline_, the above command _does_ call `Add-Member` on each object individually. The problem is the use of `$_.Name`, as Santiago notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this works:
> `$testData | Select-Object Name, Legs, @{N='CopyName';E={$_.Name}}`

This works, because you're using a **[calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties)** to define the `CopyName` property, and the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) in your `E` (`Expression`) entry allows you to refer to the `.Name` property of the *input object at hand* via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).

Note:

- Only a select few cmdlets implement support for *calculated properties*, notably `Select-Object`, `Sort-Object`, `Group-Object`, `Compare-Object` and the `Format-*` cmdlets, via a *specific parameter* sensibly named `-Property` (its type is either `[object[]]` or, in the case of `Measure-Object`, which only supports calculated properties in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, `[pspropertyexpression[]]`, and these cmdlets internally use *reflection* to determine whether a given value is a property *name* (string) or a *calculated property* (hashtable / script block)).
- By contrast, the *delay-bind script-block feature* (see below) is *part of the infrastructure* (the parameter binder), and potentially works with *any* parameter, provided it is (a) declared as pipeline-binding and (b) neither `[object]` nor `[scriptblock]`-typed - again, see below.

As an aside: You don't have to explicitly enumerate the existing properties (`Name, Legs`): you can refer to them abstractly as `*`, given that [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) as property names are supported:

`$testData | Select-Object *, @{N='CopyName';E={$_.Name}}`

---

> why doesnt this work?:
> `$testData | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "CopyName" -NotePropertyValue $_.Name`

This doesn't work, because **using `$_` to refer to the current pipeline input object only works *inside a script block***.

However, `-NotePropertyValue { $_.Name }` does *not* work either:

- Because the parameter type of `-NotePropertyValue` is `[object]` (`System.Object`), `{ $_.Name }` would become the property value *as-is*, as a script block.
- There *is* another mechanism (in addition to calculated properties) that allows determining parameter values dynamically: **[delay-bind script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters)**.

  - However, there are two prerequisites, neither of which is met by `Add-Member`'s `-NotePropertyValue` parameter:

    - The targeted parameter must be declared as *pipeline-binding* (accepting input from the pipeline).
    - The targeted parameter's type must not be `[object]` or `[scriptblock]`-typed, because you wouldn't be able to distinguish between a value that is meant to be used *as-is, as a script block* vs. an aux. script block whose purpose is to *calculate* the actual value.
  - In the case of `Add-Member`, the fact that `-NotePropertyValue`  is `[object]`-typed (to support *any* value) alone precludes support for this feature.

---

Given the above, you must call `Add-Member` on the objects in `$testData` *individually*, such as via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```
$testData |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Due to being inside the ForEach-Object script block, $_.Name
    # now refers to the current input object's .Name property.
    # Add -PassThru to also *output* the modified object.
    Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName "CopyName" -NotePropertyValue $_.Name
  }
```